# date formatting in BI Publisher - SQL data set

Tags: sql, date, bi-publisher

I want to use the date parameter in the sql query for creating data set. 
This is the query: .

`select id,name,doj from test1 where doj=:input`

But the parameter is in the 2019-01-17T18:30:00.000+00:00 format.
How do I compare in SQL.

Comment: Can you give more details on what you’re trying to do and what you’ve tried?

Answer (score 0):

Use the TO_CHAR function

```
SELECT
  TO_CHAR( sysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD' )
FROM
  dual;
```

Assuming `:input` = `2018-12-31` your code would look something like this to find a record for December 31st 2018:

```
select id,name,doj from test1 where  TO_CHAR( doj, 'YYYY-MM-DD' )=:input
```